# codeigniter - using simple_html_dom.php to get data from api

Tags: php, codeigniter, simple-html-dom

I am troubled on how to get data from an API.

I have an API that returns me this as RESPONSE;

(Be reminded that this is just a portion of the code to keep it short and understandable.)

```
<Response type="2"> 
<ack> 
    <ackstatus>OK</ackstatus> 
    <ackreason /> 
</ack> 
<dataversion>1</dataversion> 
<returntype>1</returntype> 
<topurl>http://nttbj.itp.ne.jp/0155232101/index.html?fm_id=iframecal_ad</topurl> 
<retdata>
    <![CDATA[ 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <title>店舗情報</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/medicalimport.1.1.1.css" />
    <script src="common/js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
<body lang="ja">
    <!--共通.vm-->
    <div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div id="homecontent" data-role="content">
    <div id="topinfo">
    <p><!--仮名-->リユウゲツ／オオドオリホンテン</p>
    <h1 id="basetop"><!--漢字-->柳月／大通本店</h1>
    <p><!--住所-->北海道帯広市大通南８丁目１５</p>
    <p><!--電話番号-->0155-23-2101
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</retdata>
</Response>
```

I am using simple_html_dom parser in Codeigniter. The main site for the parser is [HERE](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), you can also review the Manual. You can try and download the parser [HERE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/).

My Goal is to get data from the returned API response, which can be found in `retdata` Response, which is also a HTML data.

Here is a portion of the function that get's the API;

```
public function getCompany($industryId,$companyId,$entryName,$priority,$searchNum)
{

    $option = array( //API link here);

    $flg = $this->execApi(
        $option
    );

    return $flg;
}
```

and in the `execApi` function, i have this code;

```
protected function execApi($option, $returnName="", $sleep=1) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    sleep($sleep);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $option);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        $this->errMsg = "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        return false;
    } else {
        $response = mb_convert_encoding($response, 'UTF8', 'ASCII,JIS,UTF-8,EUC-JP,SJIS-WIN');

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);

        if ($obj === NULL) {
            $this->errMsg = "Parse error: syntax error.";
            return false;
        }

        if (empty($obj["error_code"])){
            if (empty($returnName)){
                $this->returnArray = $obj;
                return true;
            } else {
                if (empty($obj[$returnName])){
                    $this->errMsg = print_r($obj, true);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $this->returnArray = $obj[$returnName];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->errMsg = $obj["error_message"];
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So in my Model, I have this code so far;

(also a portion of the Model, to the specific function that's getting the API.)

```
<?php
require_once(APPPATH."libraries/simple_html_dom.php");
class CompanyModel extends CI_Model
{
public function getDetail($industryId,$companyId,$entryName,$priority,$searchNum) 
{

    $result = $this->itpApi->getCompany($industryId,$companyId,$entryName,$priority,$searchNum);
    $itpCompanyDetail = $this->itpApi->getReturnArray();

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($itpCompanyDetail);

    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    $html->load($xml->retdata);

    foreach($html->find('body') as $home) {
        //populate all items
        $item['name'] = $home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] h1[id="basetop"]', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['email'] = $home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 8)->plaintext;
        $item['tel'] = $home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] p', 2)->plaintext;
        $item['fax'] = $home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 3)->plaintext;
        $items = $item;
    }
    log_message('debug', 'items = ' . print_r($items, true));
    //$this->getItems($items);
}
}
?>
```

I use log to view first if there are any data got.

I'm expecting a result like;

```
Array
(
    [name] => 鰻駒形前川
    [email] => m-k105@agate.plala.or.jp           
    [tel] => 03-3841-6314 
    [fax] =>  03-3844-8851
)
```

but I cannot get any results. I am very frustrated because this took me a very long time.

Comment: I see some problems. Your cdata is broken, also `$items = $item` I assume should be `$items[] = $item`, you should initialize `$item` at the top of the loop, and `$items` outside of it - that's just at first glance